# MonoGame/XNA Mouse.GetState() always returns 0,0 position

Tags: input, xna, monogame, getstate

I'm trying to get the position of the cursor by calling the mouse class and using the GetState method but the return value is always 0,0. I've searched everywhere and all the code looks the same on other examples. I've tried alternative ways of declare the class but I get the same results.

```
public void Update() {
    var ms = Mouse.GetState();
    cursorPos = new Vector2(ms.X, ms.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mono, it's possible that `Mouse.GetState` method is extended. On some past versions there was problems `Mouse.SetState` method, could be that also problem was also in `Mouse.GetState`... so I suggest you take latest Mono framework.

Or you can try to access directly to that method.

```
var ms = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Mouse.GetState();
var mp = new Point(ms.X, ms.Y);
```